# If Data Does Not Exist Wait Else RUN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Building off of: [Efficient way to check if a SQL query will return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708815/efficient-way-to-check-if-a-sql-query-will-return-results)

Is it possible to have a wait script added at the beginning of a SQL statement ?

```
IF EXISTS(
      select * from myTable 
      where id=7)

)
SELECT * From myTable
ELSE --(Wait 1 minute, then Run Again)
SELECT * From myTable
```

Comment: Couldn't you put a wait logic in the client code where this SQL is being called?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Edit tags.

Comment: Sorry - SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WAITFOR to pause, and @@ROWCOUNT to determine whether a query returned results.  So something like:

```
set nocount on

drop table if exists #t;

--create an empty temp table
select * 
into #t
from tt 
where 1=0

while (1=1)
begin
  insert into #t
  select * from tt 

  if (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
  begin
    break;
  end

   waitfor delay '00:00:05'
end

set nocount off;
select * from #t;
```

Comment: If we wanted this code to keep running and if after 2 hours there is still no result then would we be able to write logic that will send an e-mail using msb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ?